# How can I get mouse location in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I am working recently with a js game which requires the *mouse position* to change the *background color*,
I have tried with

`event.clientX, event.clientY` and `event.pageX , event.pageY`

and now it had became:-

```
function l(){
    let x = event.pageX ;
    let y = event.pageY;
    document.bgColor = 'rgb($(x),$(y),$((x/2+y/2))'
};

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove',l());
```

but ,still it gives error,

```
uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined
```

If anyone solves my problem, a Great Thanks for him in advance
Have a good time :-)

Comment: the second argument to addEventListener needs to be a function, not the result of calling a function ... fix: `document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', l);`

Comment: `l` should have `event` as an argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var movementFunction = function (event) { 
    console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY);
    let x = event.pageX ;
    let y = event.pageY;
    document.bgColor = `rgb(${x}, ${y}, ${(x/2+y/2)}`
}

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', movementFunction);
```

Comment: Yes, but why? Answers with an explanation and good description of what was changed are much better.